# How to bypass simple zener diode voltage regulation at low volts?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

[image]

Is there a simple circuit to automatically bypass zener diode regulation at a voltage lower than its rating?

I have a bunch of simple circuit designs that accept 11-15VDC but in the intended industry there are two common power supply voltages used 12VDC and 24VDC.

It would be advantageous if my designs could work on both power supply options without the need for separate power input terminals or manual switching.

12VDC zener regulation draws too much current @ 24VDC. I have implemented a 15V zener/series resistor circuit and it works great but obviously, below 15VDC it drops voltage. I could add a simple switch to bypass the regulation for 12V applications but I would like to be smart and add a MOSFET or similar to do this automatically.

The voltage differences across Rs between 12 and 24VDC seem suited to MOSFET switching but I am struggling to work out the circuit and placement.

Any help would be appreciated. It's ok for the output voltage to vary anywhere within 11-15VDC.

The "load" circuits draw 200mA worst case and are resistive with built-in flyback protection.

Comment: Why not just use an LDO regulator instead?

Comment: I will have a better look. Initial results don't offer many in the range if you allow for 24VDC actually being closer to 28V from the power supply. There are more options at 150mA and under which would do for some but not all of my applications.

Comment: That depends on what is the circuit after the zener. If you need your circuit to be powered with 11V to 28V supply range, then you need such a power supply circuit or module.

Comment: You could use a Schmitt trigger that drives a mosfet which, in turn, drives an OpAmp voltage regulator.

Comment: For 24V input, dropping down to 15V means dropping 9V across the series device (whatever that happens to be, resistor or transistor) and at 200mA this is 1.8W of power.  Is that amount of power loss OK?  Do you need short-circuit protection?  If the load draws more than 200mA, is reducing Vout OK?   What about load regulation, is it OK for Vout to vary (droop) as load current increases (from 0 to 200mA)?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but for the system parameters you are targeting (input voltage range: 10-36V,  output voltage:12V, output current < 500mA) there is a lot to be said for the small switching alternatives to the linear 7412 regulators.

[image]

They come in a range of quality/price points, from top of the line units from the likes of [Murata](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807028260894/dms-78xxsr.pd) and [Recom](https://recom-power.com/en/products/switching-regulators/switching-regulators-sip/rec-s-R-78-0.5.html) (~$7/unit) to no name Chinese units (~$1/unit).

Dead simple to use (3 pins, Vin, Vout, Gnd), multiple vendors, high efficiency, very reliable and cheap.

Comment: I had considered these but they drop too much voltage at the low end which leaves me in the same position. 15V min Vin for both.

Comment: There are similar buck-boost modules which will support vin<vout as well as vin>out.

Comment: Awesome. Will check em out.